# Instant Run not working in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting a `DexArchiveBuilderException` with instant run on Android studio 3.0. Gradle builds fine, but I get an error trying to deploy the `apk`.

Disabling instant run fixes the issue.

How can I get this working with instant run?

Full error:

```
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/vedantagarwala/dunzo/cappuccino/android-final/demo/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/9
```

// Top-level build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

ext {

    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"

    targetSdkVersion = 22
    minSdkVersion = 15
    androidSupportLibVersion = "25.3.1"
    googlePlayServiceVersion = "10.0.1";
    resConfigs = ["en"];
    // You can also create properties to specify versions for dependencies.
    // Having consistent versions between modules can avoid conflicts with behavior.
}
```

I have tried solutions online, like upgrading/downgrading gradle and/or dependencies, but nothing worked.

**JDK:**

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: did you enable instant run from android studio setting?

Comment: @HemantParmar Yes. The error occours only when instant run is on.

Comment: @vedant1811 Any solution to that so far? I'm getting an exception related to dex too with Instant Run and Android 3.0.

Comment: Do you have Java (JDK) 8 installed on your machine or Java 9?

Comment: Simply Upgrade your gradle to 4.x and that will solve the problem.

Comment: can you show your app level build.gradle?

Answer (score 2):

if your device running on MIUI, go to Developer Settings -> Turn on MIUI optimization and turn it off. then you need to restart your device and recompile the code.
Instant Run should be up and running again!